# Reputation stopped growing at 1451. Why?

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation stopped changing on June 28th
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/6355/osvaldo?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2012-08-12%2016:27:35Z

But I've made a reply and had 3 upvotes on the Jully 6. And My answer was accepted.
[Free open source feature request web site platform?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32132/free-open-source-feature-request-web-site-platform/32134#32134)

Anyway it's the first time my reputation is stalled for so long... Is this a bug or is there another reason? Usually old answers contributed to small increases in reputation every week...

Answer (score 3):

It appears as though the answer you cited - [Free open source feature request web site platform?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32132/free-open-source-feature-request-web-site-platform/32134#32134) - is marked Community Wiki and will therefore not accrue rep.

Comment: If you look at the edit history for that question, it states: "Post Made Community Wiki by _Osvaldo_"